# iOS sending base64 data by post divided in two

Tags: php, ios, post, base64

Here is my problem :

I'm sending base64 encoded data to my server from an iOS device. But sometimes, data seem to arrive divided in two requests.

On the device side I do :

```
NSString *base64Data = [self base64forData:myData];
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myRequestURL]; //like www.myaddress.com/myPHP.php

[myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[myRequest setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mydata=%@&type=%d",base64Data] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Here is the encoding function :

```
- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {

    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i,i2;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        for (i2=0; i2<3; i2++) {
            value <<= 8;
            if (i+i2 < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[i+i2]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

On my server side, in myPHP.php, I use : `$_REQUEST['mydata'];` , `$_REQUEST['type'];` and `file_get_contents('php://input');` to retrieve my data.

In case of problem, the first time, php get the first part of the HTTPBody. And then, it's call a second time with the end of the request. I can see that `file_get_contents('php://input');` do not receive entirely my HTTPBody. For example I can receive a part of `mydata` in a first call, and then the end of `mydata` with `type`.

If I send :

```
mydata=blablabla&type=totototo
```

I can received it divided in

```
mydata=blab
labla&type=tototo
```

Is the problem on the device side? problem with converting data in base64? setting the HTTPBody with NSASCIIStringEncoding ? special char corrupting the data retrieved by my server?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `i` and `i2` for loop variables? That really hurts the eyes. why not the more traditional `i` and `j`?

Comment: Well... you're write. It's a method pasted from the web.

Comment: @Marc Why not name them in a more meaningful way than i & j, this is not Fortran where i,j,k,l,m,n were integers.